# How to parse xml data which have special characters in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to parse xml data which have special characters ( ' , " , < , > etc) in iOS? In NSXmlParser's delegate, when it reads special characters ( ' , & ), it thinks this is open new eplement? How can i ignore those special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML with those characters is invalid, unless they are contained within a CDATA. (In which case the xml parser shouldn't have a problem with them.)

I'd recommend running your XML through a [validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) and fixing any issues it finds.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) 
It need 2 steps to parse xml data which have special characters.
Step 1: Replace special characters with valid character which list in this link http://xml.silmaril.ie/authors/specials/
Step 2: Concatenate strings which breaked when you read it. 
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/f